# Restrict certain postcodes from being entered into form input

Tags: jquery, validation

Am using a script at the moment to prevent certain postcodes being entered into the relevant input field.

```
<script>
function checkForm()
{
  var a=document.forms["InsertFrm"]["Postcode"].value;

 if(a == "4001" || "4002") {
  alert("Sorry. This Membership is only available to visitors to the Area!");
  return false;
  }

  }
  </script>
```

then on Form Submit, this code runs.. - no probs.

However, would like to update (using jquery still) - a warning appears on entry and not having to wait until submitting?

Comment: Please pay attention to tag descriptions.  The [tag:jquery-validate] tag is only for questions about the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are using is plain javascript.

You may use jquery's keyup event to do what you need.

```
<script>
  function checkForm() {
    var a=document.forms["InsertFrm"]["Postcode"].value;
    // change your condition to this as "4002" is always true
    if(a == "4001" || a == "4002") {
      alert("Sorry. This Membership is only available to visitors to the Area!");
      return false;
    }
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').on('keyup', function(evt) {
      checkForm();
    });
    $('form').on('submit', function(evt) {
      checkForm();
    });
  });
</script>
```

replace `$('input')` with your input field, i.e. `$('input#postcode')` and 
 `$('form')` with your input field, i.e. `$('form#addressform')`

You also need to change your condition as in `if(a == "4001" || "4002")` "4002" will always be true. It needs to be `if(a == "4001" || a == "4002")`

You can also disable the submit button, but that's easy to overcome on the client side, so using the submit listener will be safer at this point.

Just for fun, you could also try this:

```
function checkForm() {
    var a=document.forms["InsertFrm"]["Postcode"].value;
    // change your condition to this as "4002" is always true
    if(a == "4001" || a == "4002") {
      alert("Sorry. This Membership is only available to visitors to the Area!");
      $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
      return false;
    } else {
      $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks F - close but as soon as I enter any number (eg even just 1 by itself), it immediately comes up with the warning.

Comment: Yes sorry, you need to update your if condition. I'll update the code block

Comment: Sorry, to add, am using Bootstrap and  Validator v0.10.2 for Bootstrap 3, by @1000hz

Comment: Thx F - Much better.  Now, it actually doesn't stop the form being submitted if 4001 or 4002 entered.  The visitor can close the warning popup, but still continue... Can we take it one step further so they cannot submit??  My bad, maybe should have initially mentioned. The original code was onsubmit=blah

Comment: Used your "Just for Fun"..  Had me stumped, it kept submitting every time I clicked "Close" on the popup.  Then realised I used the bootstrap <button> to submit NOT input!! So changed accordingly and works better than good.  Thank you F....